# Twig email - show and hide object

Tags: php, email, twig

Currently using Twig to produce my email template. I am having some difficulties getting my head around the following scenario.

I have 2 products which are being pushed to my email template, however, one of the products is 'Gift wrap'. The idea is not to show GIFT WRAP amongst my product list, but instead, show it in the summary area, where SHIPPING, SUBTOTAL AND TOTAL can be found.

I am able to hide GIFT WRAP from the list, however, having issues with the summary section.

This is what I have so far:

```
<!-- Summary section -->
{% for item in items %}
   {% if item.title == 'Gift wrap' %}                 
       Show gift wrap
   {% else %} 
       Dont show giftwrap
       But now show another element
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately 'don't show gift wrap' still shows. If anyone could help me, it would be very much appreciated.

As requested here is a part of my template

```
 {% for item in items %}
     {% if item.title == 'Gift wrap' %}                 
          <tr>
             <td style="border-top: 2px solid #202020;"></td>
             <td style="padding-left: 10px; border-top: 2px solid #202020; padding-top: 20px; font-family: 'Open sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-weight: 300;" width="100px">
                 Subtotal
             </td>
             <td style="border-top: 2px solid #202020; padding-top: 20px; font-family: 'Open sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-weight: 300;" align="right" width="100px">
                 £{{ subtotal - item.totals.data.rounded.with_tax }}
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px; font-family: 'Open sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-weight: 300;" width="100px">
                  Gift wrap
             </td>
             <td style="padding-top: 10px; font-family: 'Open sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-weight: 300;" align="right" width="100px">
                  {{ item.totals.data.formatted.with_tax }}
              </td>
          </tr>
     {% else %}
          <tr>
               <td>
                   <p>Add this if gift wrap has not be added to customers order</p>
               </td>
          </tr>
     {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is it "still showing" because you have multiple items? The template you have provided works for me.

Comment: Yes there is multiple items

Comment: If those items names are anything but "Gift wrap" then the above template will show `Dont show giftwrap`. Take out `Dont show giftwrap` and it'll be working as you desire, no?

Comment: I wish I could, however I need to insert another element in there. I will update the code above to hopefully make it a little clearer

Comment: Post full template and expected output

Comment: Do you think I should be using something along the lines of "if('Gift wrap' is inArray)" If so, how would i achieve this in Twig??

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing to do what you want, you will need to keep a `flag` whether the `Gift wrap` is in the items. Here is how you would solve this by using a `flag`:

```
{% set has_gift_wrap = false %}
{% for item in items %}
    {% if item.title == 'Gift wrap' %}
        {% set has_gift_wrap = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
 ...
 ...
{% if has_gift_wrap %}                 
    <tr>
     <td style="border-top: 2px solid #202020;"></td>
     <td style="padding-left: 10px; border-top: 2px solid #202020; padding-top: 20px; font-family: 'Open sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-weight: 300;" width="100px">
         Subtotal
     </td>
     <td style="border-top: 2px solid #202020; padding-top: 20px; font-family: 'Open sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-weight: 300;" align="right" width="100px">
         £{{ subtotal - item.totals.data.rounded.with_tax }}
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px; font-family: 'Open sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-weight: 300;" width="100px">
          Gift wrap
     </td>
     <td style="padding-top: 10px; font-family: 'Open sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-weight: 300;" align="right" width="100px">
          {{ item.totals.data.formatted.with_tax }}
      </td>
    </tr>
{% else %}
    <tr>
       <td>
           <p>Add this if gift wrap has not be added to customers order</p>
       </td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
```

**sidenote**: *You can't use `{% if "Gift wrap" in items %}` because `Gift wrap` is stored inside an attribute*.